# how to create sample library projects in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries

what are the steps to create library projects in android?

Now I am in beginning stage , and don't know what are the things to do. Can any one provide me any sample link that contains steps in creating sample library projects?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will help you.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html